# MySQL request from category with LIKE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query below. My `q.catid = 13` (`category_id`) but this query return me results from another categories. Where is my mistake?

```
SELECT q.*, u.name, u.username, u.email, c.title AS category_name, COUNT(a.id) AS answers 
FROM `#__questions` AS q 
LEFT JOIN `#__answers` AS a ON a.question_id = q.id 
LEFT JOIN `#__users` AS u ON q.created_by = u.id 
LEFT JOIN `#__categories` AS c ON q.catid = c.id    
WHERE 1=1 
AND q.catid = 13 
AND q.title LIKE "%3%" 
OR q.introtext LIKE "%3%" 
GROUP BY q.id 
ORDER BY q.created DESC
```

Comment: Why the `WHERE 1=1` ?

Comment: @Havenard, that's a common construction in query builders - it means that additional clauses are always prefixed by `AND`.

Comment: OP, if you can write your question titles without tag devices (i.e.  the bar), that is helpful. This has been discussed on _Meta_ extensively, and the community prefers titles without. If you can word as ordinary English, or even better as a question, that works best here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Because `and` binds stronger than `or`. It is called *operator precedence*.

Use parentheses

```
WHERE 1=1 
AND q.catid = 13 
AND (q.title LIKE "%3%" OR q.introtext LIKE "%3%")
```

**Without** parentheses your query currently resolves to

```
WHERE (1=1 AND q.catid = 13 AND q.title LIKE "%3%")
OR q.introtext LIKE "%3%"
```